# Get Nodes from a Tree

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

Given

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Tree Int Tree

collectnode :: Int -> [Tree] -> [Int]

collectnode n (Leaf x)
            |x > n = [x]
            |otherwise = []
collectnode n (Node t1 n t2)
            |n1 > n = (collectnode n tr1) ++ [n1] ++ (collectnode n tr2)
            |otherwise = (collectnode n tr1) ++ (collectnode n tr2)
```

This code is basically collecting all nodes that are greater than N.

I understand that in the base case we are looking at a particular leaf and checking if its greater than n and if it is we add to list otherwise we don't. However i don't understand the other part of the solution at all. can someone please break it down for me or simplify it as much as possible? i would really appreciate it.

Comment: There appears to be a typo. `collectnode n (Node t1 n t2)` should read `collectnode n (Node t1 n1 t2)`, although actually I would find it much clearer if it used `x` in that case as well, instead of `n1`.

Comment: also, appears to be a typo in the type of `collectnode`. Looking at the use, it must be `collectnode :: Int -> Tree -> [Int]`. And identifiers not used right. `collectnode n (Node tr1 n1 tr2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other part of the solution handles the case where `collectnode` is called with `n` and a `Node` that has a left tree, a value, and a right tree. We need to recursively perform `collectnode` on the left and right subtrees, and we also need to include the value of this `Node`, if and only if it is greater than `n`. There are two cases to consider:

`|n1 > n = (collectnode n tr1) ++ [n1] ++ (collectnode n tr2)`

In this case, `n1 > n` so we want to include all the results produced by recursively collecting the left subtree, the value of the current node, and all the results produced by recursively collecting the right subtree.

`|otherwise = (collectnode n tr1) ++ (collectnode n tr2)`

In this case, the value from the current node should not be included, so we only collect the values from the left and right subtrees. The result is the concatenation of both of them.

It doesn't recurse forever, naturally, because at some point as we collect subtrees we get down to the `Leaf` nodes which are handled by the base case.